# how to create a brought forward balance in crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

I have a report with credit, debit and balance column. Reports works fine. But i need this report with a date range. while i am running this report in a date couldn't get the actual balance in this report. Reports need a line with brought forward balance. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

```
Whileprintingrecords;
Shared Numbervar balance;
Shared Numbervar display;

balance:={@debit}-{@credit};
display:=display+balance;
display
```

Comment: explain more clearly what is the problem. if possible with a screenshot of how report design looks like

Comment: need brought forward balance in my report

Comment: Trying using a stored procedure as your data set instead. You can pass parameters that way.